# Set password on app and give password to specific people making the app private?

Tags: ios, xcode

The B2B program Apple has isn't available in my country and in looking for another way to give my apps to a business privately so that only that business or the people in it can use the app. I was wondering , is Apple ok with me putting a password on my app so that anyone can download it but only someone who knows the password can use it?

Comment: so what will be the use for all the other users? you should ask Apple's support but the answer will probably be no. look at this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579491/can-i-distribute-my-iphone-app-for-only-certain-people. It suggests the same solution as yours more or less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allowed to publish an app that targets only a certain group of users, says the Apple guidelines for publishing on the app store. With that password restriction you're against that rule.

Now, that being said, you could buy an entreprise developer account and simply use the Over-the-Air system, if you're aware of how it works.

If not, look at my brief description here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26043004/3603502

Comment: Not strictly true, you can provide an account for Apple to use when reviewing the app. If the app does at least _something_ when a user downloads it, but the full functionality is available with a password then it's generally okay. I've put two separate large apps on the store such as this. The images in the app store are a bit boring, obviously, but they made it through review.